# Customize Firebase StorageException toast

Tags: firebase, exception, storage, toast

I have specified a rule to limit the size of an image that can be written to Firebase Storage, however the current Toast message is "User does not have permission to access this object." when the file exceeds the maximum size limit.

Is there any way to customize the Toast message? The current message is confusing to the user and should rather say "Image size too big. Please select an image that is smaller than 5MB" for example.

See current Storage rules below:

```
    rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      // Only allow uploads of any image file that's less than 10MB
      allow write: if request.auth != null
      && request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
      && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you'll get from Firebase due to the security rules is always going to be the same, and there's no way to customize it.

To show a different message in your app, you'll want to detect the same condition as the rules do in your application code. That also means you can do this before the upload starts, saving your users some bandwidth charges.